# UTM coordinate import using csv table

Tags: qgis, coordinates, csv, import

I would like to import (in order to create a point layer) in QGIS a csv table with UTMREF/MGRS-coordinates. The coordinates in the column look like this 32UMV6134481745. Usually QGIS requires an X and Y field. Is there a possibility in the import, or do I have to separate or even transfer the coordinates in the csv before import?

Answer (score 4):

I have no knowledge about MGRS coordinates system, but it seems [Lat Lon Tools](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/latlontools/) is the plugin you are looking for.

1. Read the CSV file into QGIS as an `attribute only` table.

   `Layer | Add Layer | Add Delimited Text Layer`

   - File format: CSV
   - Geometry definition: No geometry (attribute only table)
   - Hit [OK]. You will see new layer (table) listed in the layer panel.
2. Install and run `Lat Lon Tools`

   `Plugins | Lat Lon Tools | MGRS Conversions | MGRS to Geometry`

   - Input Table/Layer: your MGRS layer
   - Field Containing MGRS Coordinates: assign field name
   - Hit [OK]

That's all. I may be wrong but the point `32UMV6134481745` returned Lon= `8.46627`, Lat= `49.48711`.